# Como enviar e-mail a cada novo registro?

Tags: postgresql

Estou utilizando **Postgres 9.6** em um projeto e um dos requisitos é que o sistema envie um e-mail a cada novo cliente.

**1 - Trigger é uma boa maneira de fazer?**

**2 - Se tratando de desempenho. Qual seria o impacto em enviar esses e-mails por trigger?**

**3 - Ou isso é um trabalho para um serviço em segundo plano ?**

Comment: Primeiramente: Você tem um backend para inserir os dados no banco?  Eu não sei se tem como fazer pelo postgree, mas como e-mail costuma demorar alguns segundos para envio (se tratando de SMTP), eu evitaria fazer isso.

Comment: Pois é essa a minha dúvida a questão justamente na demora no envio iria atrasar o processo de CRUD

Comment: Fabrício, dependendo da situação, cabe analisar se o trigger poderia disparar uma linha de comando. Aí talvez você poderia usar o SendMail.

Comment: Mal lhe pergunte: Que so vocÊ usa?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters é uma idéia muito útil

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nesse bagulho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296084/execute-external-program-with-trigger-in-postgres-9-4)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters "Que so vocÊ usa? "  linguagem de programação?

Comment: SO = Sistema operacional.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79559/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-fabricio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a resposta anterior disse, você deve pensar na questão do desempenho. E respondendo diretamente a sua pergunta sobre "Ou isso é um trabalho para um serviço em segundo plano?", eu diria que seria recomendável que sim.

Pense nos problemas que poderia ser ocasionados se você inseri-se 10 registros e, de repente, 3 desses processos de envio de e-mail travam. Ou mesmo pense num cenário, caso estivesse usando um SMTP da g-mail por exemplo, e essa requisição demorasse uns 15 segundos para ser resolvidas (como já aconteceu comigo em alguns casos). Isso com toda certeza afetaria a performance do seu banco de dados.

Eu pensaria numa outra questão: não é responsabilidade do meu banco de dados enviar um e-mail. Então, eu faria isso sim através de uma linha de comando ou, como já foi sugerido, utilizando um backend de uma aplicação para fazer isso.

Como eu sugeri no meu comentário, eu poderia cogitar usar um TRIGGER para disparar um comando rodando em Background, conforme o link abaixo:

- [execute external program with trigger in postgres 9.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296084/execute-external-program-with-trigger-in-postgres-9-4)

Na minha humilde opinião: Acho que esse tipo de coisa deve ser feito na camada da aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Eu não faria isso usando o banco de dados, faria isso usando a linguagem de programação. A maioria das linguagens atuais tem suporte a execução de tarefas assíncronas, o que ajuda no caso de demora no envio.

Aqui neste link fala porque não é uma boa ideia enviar e-mails usando o banco de dados: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12003516/887882

> Enviar email diretamente do banco de dados pode não ser uma boa ideia.
>   E se a resolução do DNS for lenta e tudo for interrompido em 30
>   segundos e expirar? E se o seu servidor de e-mail estiver com
>   problemas e demorar 5 minutos para aceitar mensagens?  Você obterá
>   sessões de banco de dados suspensas em seu gatilho até que esteja em
>   max_connections e, de repente, não poderá fazer nada, a não ser
>   aguardar ou começar a cancelar manualmente as transações.

Comment: *maioria das linguagens atuais tem suporte a execução de tarefas assíncronas*... Vou chorar, php não tem :\

Comment: Como o PHP não tem, você pode criar um pequeno arquivo PHP que faça isso e executar em background.

Comment: E eu não tenho tanta certeza, mas existem algumas bibliotecas PHP que permitem multithread.

Comment: Eu só estava brincando, Elisângela. Eu atualmente uso o Laravel (framework php) para criar Queues (filas) no banco de dados e executo elas em outro plano.